# How to pass pendingInent in Intent.putExtra; to start pendingIntent from anotherActivty

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, gson, android-pendingintent

I'm trying a start a UI activity from the NotificationListiner service,Then In UI
when user clicks on yes: perform pendingIntent();else: finish()

I tried to achieve the above with `Dialog,AlertDialog` but since `NotificationListiner` was a background service it didn't work.
Then made a new `Activity`;

Tried with `Gson`

`SbnContainer.kt`

```
class SbnContainer {
    lateinit var notification: Notification
    lateinit var title: String
    lateinit var desc: String
    constructor(){
        Log.d("TAG", "Salaam")
    }
    constructor(notification: Notification, title:String, desc:String){
        this.notification = notification
        this.title= title
        this.desc = desc
    }
}
```

Calling From `NotificationService`

```
    var i = Intent(this,CAlertWindow::class.java)
    i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    val gson = Gson()
    var a = SbnContainer(sbn.notification, title, desc)
    val myJson = gson.toJson(a)
    i.putExtra("PACKAGE", myJson)
    startActivity(i)
```

Receiving from `CAlertWindow(AppCompatActivity)`

```
        val gson = Gson()
        val ob: SbnContainer = gson.fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("PACKAGE"), SbnContainer::class.java)
        pendingIntent = ob.notification.contentIntent
        alertWindowLayoutBinding.alrTitle.text = ob.title
        alertWindowLayoutBinding.alrDesc.text = ob.desc
        Log.d("Abdx79/AlertWindow", "In Alert Window")
        alertWindowLayoutBinding.alrOpnB.setOnClickListener {
            pendingIntent.send()
        }
        alertWindowLayoutBinding.alrDntB.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
```

Error on calling `startActivity(i)`

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abdx79.notifications_manager/com.abdx79.notifications_manager.CAlertWindow}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.lang.CharSequence. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.lang.CharSequence. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

So how can I solve this.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Serializable` for passing a object like ->

```
 class Shop(
            val name: String,
            val details: String?,
            val id: Int,
            ):Serializable
```

now pass this Shop class like

```
 var shop = Shop("name","details",1)
    val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java).putExtra(
                "SHOP",
                shop 
            )
    startActivity(intent)
```

now receive this shop class from another activity

```
 val shope = intent.getSerializableExtra("SHOP") as Shop
```

you can also use `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable`

Comment: i get this error with above approach `W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.abdx79.notifications_manager.SbnContainer)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1714)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1662)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1583)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)`